# How to install get_iplayer in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, plugin

I have just installed Linux Fedora 17. (I have upgraded from Fedora 12, new computer, vendor installed 20, lots of problems, already got DVD for 17 so used that, now everything fine, until ... ) I want to use BBC i-player, needs plug-in. I have installed Adobe Flash Player, still no go. After searching the Web, and trying lots of suggestions in vain, it seems that I should have `get_iplayer` already, but I don't, nor can I install it:

```
[root@Hugh harry]# get_iplayer
bash: get_iplayer: command not found...
[root@Hugh harry]# yum install get_iplayer
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
No package get_iplayer available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@Hugh harry]#
```

Have I done, missed, or overlooked something obvious? Please, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the  [RPM Fusion](http://www.rpmfusion.org/)  repositories to have "Free World" package, like `get_iplayer`. The most common way to add the repo:

```
su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'
```

Then update your package list and install `get_iplayer` using yum:

```
yum install get_iplayer
```

Comment: Oooo switching distros 8-)